# Error when importing Matplotlib using Anaconda IDE

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I have just installed Anaconda 3 and I'm trying to use Pylab to plot a function . But when using the line code :`from matplotlib import *` , I get the following error , that I've been trying to solve for 3 days . I already tried the conda update -all, or instaling a previous version of Matplotlib .
Here is the error :

```
runfile('C:/Users/USUARIO/.spyder2-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/USUARIO/.spyder2-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-9b55d1cb87fc>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/USUARIO/.spyder2-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/USUARIO/.spyder2-py3')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/USUARIO/.spyder2-py3/temp.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pylab import *

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 231, in <module>
    import matplotlib.finance

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\finance.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection, PolyCollection

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 62, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py", line 15, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1421, in <module>
    _rebuild()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1406, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1044, in __init__
    self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 313, in findSystemFonts
    for f in win32InstalledFonts(fontdir):

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 231, in win32InstalledFonts
    direc = os.path.abspath(direc).lower()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 535, in abspath
    path = _getfullpathname(path)

ValueError: _getfullpathname: embedded null character`
```

Any idea on how to fix it ?

Comment: Drop into the debugger and look at what the font name is.

Comment: Okay for anyone having the same issue , I fixed it by modifying the font_manager.py , changing some lines the win32installedfont() by this :
`key, direc, any = winreg.EnumValue( local, j)
if not is_string_like(direc):
    continue
if not os.path.dirname(direc):
    direc = os.path.join(directory, direc)
direc = direc.split('\0', 1)[0]`